# React - Redirect to a default path if path doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was creating a simple react app. I just want to know how to redirect to a certain path if the inputted path doesn't exist.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './screens/HomePage/home';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export { App };
```

Let say I went to "localhost:3000/login", but since the path doesn't exist I want it to automatically redirect to "localhost:3000" as the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by doing this:

I created a MissingRoute.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function MissingRoute() {
 return < Navigate to={{pathname: '/'}} / >
}

export { MissingRoute }
```

Then use it as an element in the routes:

```js
<Routes>
 <Route path="*" element={<MissingRoute/>} />
</Routes>
```

For older versions of react, you might need to do it differently and use "Redirect" instead of "Navigate"

It might be convoluted. Let me know if there is a cleaner way to do this. But this is what I got for now.

Answer (score 6):

you can add `*` to your path, so if the existing path does not match, then it hits this route, and you can redirect to wherever you want.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './screens/HomePage/home';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
        <Route path="/some-existing" element={<SomeComponent />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<HomePage />} /> // page-not-found route
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export { App };
```

Comment: This way you will render `HomePage` on every matched URL and _not_ redirect.

Comment: No, it'll render component if the path does match. In here, if you can match the path of `/some-existing` then it'll render `<SomeComponent` . But if you hit different path (some random) it'll render `<HomePage />`.

Comment: Your are right, but the question is how to redirect to the root URL, not how to render same content on (some random) path.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use [`Redirect`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) component in the last Route of the list:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './screens/HomePage/home';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <HomePage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export { App };
```

Comment: In v6 there is no `Redirect` import. So we can use `Navigate`. Am I correct?

Comment: I'd follow the changelog https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#remove-redirects-inside-switch

Answer (score 3):

In react-router v6, you could do something like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to='/' replace />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```